# How to toggle between responsive and non-responsive design

Tags: responsive-design

Ok, so with the help of a couple sites, I was able to put this code together to inactivate the responsive coding for a website and activate the non-responsive coding. However, when the link is clicked again, it doesn't perform this function in reverse.

I tried using ".toggle", but that doesn't work. Which event should I be using to get this effect? Any help would be great!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#togglerwd").click(function() {
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="togglerwd">Toggle Responsive Layout</a>
```

Comment: Just use a simple flag to store what “state” the site is currently in, and then assign one value or the other to the viewport meta content based on that …

Comment: Hey CBroe, thank you, but I have no idea what that means. I'm still a novice when it comes to jQuery. Isn't there an event that will allow the code to be active and inactive when the hyperlink is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there an event that will allow the code to be active and inactive when the hyperlink is clicked?

The click itself is the event that is happening – but that event does not know anything about what “state” your page is currently in.

A “flag” is a common programming basic, and not specific to jQuery or JavaScript. Basically it is just a variable with a value that alternates between true and false, and based on which you decide what to do.

It would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // set the initial flag value, we assume your page “starts” in responsive mode
    var isResponsive = true;

    $("#togglerwd").click(function() {
        // check flag, to see what state the page is in
        if(isResponsive) {
          // set viewport meta to “non-responsive”
          $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
          // remember current state in flag for check on next click
          isResponsive = false;
        }
        else {
          // set viewport meta to “responsive”
          $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width');
          // remember current state in flag for check on next click
          isResponsive = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help CBroe, but I ended up creating the exact solution I wanted. Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#togglerwd").click(function() {
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
  });
    $("#togglerrl").click(function() {
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width');
  });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="togglerwd">Full Site | </a>
<a href="#" id="togglerrl">Responsive Layout</a>
```